# List which columns have a full-text index in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

How do I list all tables / columns in my database that have a full-text index?

Looking for answer similar to: [List which columns have a full-text index in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949435/list-which-columns-have-a-full-text-index-in-sql-server-2005), but for SQL Server 2000 [sighs]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list the tables:

```
EXEC sp_help_fulltext_tables;
```

To list the columns for each table:

```
EXEC sp_help_fulltext_columns;
```

Note this will fail if full-text is not enabled.

If you want to customize the output, just examine the text of these two procedures to see what they are doing (I don't have a 2000 instance handy, so can't confirm, but keep in mind that these stored procedures might have system syntax that you can't execute or access system tables that you can't query directly).

```
EXEC sp_helptext sp_help_fulltext_tables;
EXEC sp_helptext sp_help_fulltext_columns;
```

sp_help_fulltext_tables:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933422%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

sp_help_fulltext_columns:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933445%28v=sql.80%29.aspx