# How to use Microsoft SQL CONTAINS to search for rows where the column contains a word at any position, similar to LIKE '%word%'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

My Customer table has a full-text index on column Name. (I checked that the column is full-text index by using this [answer](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949435/list-which-columns-have-a-full-text-index-in-sql-server-2005) and by right clicking on the column -> properties -> Full Text = true)

The names are usually first name and surname, e.g.

```
Name
---------------
Joe
Joe Doe
Joe Bar
Foo Joe
Alice Bob
Charles David
Elizabeth Fred
```

When I search for all customers where the name contains the word "Doe" using the [CONTAINS predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT * FROM mst_Customers WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'Doe')
```

nothing is returned

When I search for all customers where the name contains "Joe"

```
SELECT * FROM mst_Customers WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'Joe')
```

the first 3 records are turned (instead of all 4 customers where the name contains the word Joe)

```
Name
---------------
Joe
Joe Doe
Joe Bar
```

How do I use `CONTAINS` to return all customers that somewhere in the name contain "Doe"?

The equivalent using LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM mst_Customers WHERE Name LIKE '%Doe%'
```

gives me the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly... Demo :

```
CREATE TABLE T_NOM
(NOM_ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_NOM PRIMARY KEY, 
 NOM_NOM VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO T_NOM VALUES 
('Joe'), 
('Joe Doe'), 
('Joe Bar'), 
('Foo Joe'), 
('Alice Bob'), 
('Charles David'), 
('Elizabeth Fred');
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FT;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON T_NOM (NOM_NOM) KEY INDEX PK_NOM ON FT;
GO

SELECT * FROM T_NOM WHERE CONTAINS(NOM_NOM,'Doe');
```

Comment: Thanks SQLpro. I posted a follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65600919/why-does-microsoft-sql-contains-not-work-for-the-word-said) because the problem seems to be with a specific surname `Said`. Not sure what is going on.