# Why does Microsoft SQL CONTAINS not work for the word 'Said'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

*(This a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597903/how-to-use-microsoft-sql-contains-to-search-for-rows-where-the-column-contains-a))*

I have a table with customers. The table has one column `Name` that has a full text index. One of the customers has the surname 'Said' and another has the surname 'Saiid'.

```
Name
---------
Joe Said
Joe Saiid
```

When I query for 'Said' using the [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) predicate nothing is returned. But querying for 'Saiid' using `CONTAINS` returns the record.

---

Here is a demo, using the suggestion from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65599563/14952570)

```
CREATE TABLE T_NOM
(NOM_ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_NOM PRIMARY KEY, 
NOM_NOM VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO T_NOM VALUES 
('Joe'), 
('Joe Doe'), 
('Joe Bar'), 
('Foo Joe'), 
('Alice Bob'), 
('Charles David'), 
('Elizabeth Fred'),
('Joe Said'), 
('Joe Saiid')
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FT;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON T_NOM (NOM_NOM) KEY INDEX PK_NOM ON FT;
GO
```

Again, this returns nothing

```
SELECT * FROM T_NOM WHERE CONTAINS(NOM_NOM,'Saiid');
```

These 2 queries return the record for Joe Said and Joe Doe respectively.

```
SELECT * FROM T_NOM WHERE CONTAINS(NOM_NOM,'Said');
SELECT * FROM T_NOM WHERE CONTAINS(NOM_NOM,'Doe');
```

Comment: Probably because it is a stop word.  You need to read the documentation on how full text indexes work quite carefully.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the tip. In the database there is no Storage -> Full Text Stoplists ... where else could stop lists be stored?

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, yes that answers my question. Something with stop words. If I switch off the stop list for that table / full index, the query works.

Comment: You can create your own list of stopwords and also this list can be fill with the default one in which you will remove the 'said' word...